# xml xslt help - transform is not rendering correctly

Tags: asp.net, xml, wcf, xslt

i have an xml file like for binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyCustomer>
  <Customers>
    <CutomerCode>C001</CutomerCode>
    <CustomerName>Shahbaz</CustomerName>
    <City>Karachi</City>
    <Country>Pakistan</Country>
  </Customers>
  <Customers>
    <CutomerCode>C002</CutomerCode>
    <CustomerName>Imran</CustomerName>
    <City>Lahore</City>
    <Country>Pakistan</Country>
  </Customers>
</MyCustomer>
```

I am Applying the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 version="1.0">

 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="MyCustomer">
   <xsl:copy>
     <Customers>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="Customers/*"/>
     </Customers>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="Customers/*">
   <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="Customers/City">
      <xsl:element name="Address">
         <xsl:element name="City">
       <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="Customers/Country">
      <xsl:element name="Address">
         <xsl:element name="Country">
       <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this XSLT is giving me the result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyCustomer>
  <Customers>
    <CutomerCode>C001</CutomerCode>
    <CustomerName>Shahbaz</CustomerName>
    <Address>
      <City>Karachi</City>
    </Address>
    <Address>
      <Couontry>Pakistan</Couontry>
    </Address>
    <CutomerCode>C002</CutomerCode>
    <CustomerName>Imran</CustomerName>
    <Address>
      <City>Lahore</City>
    </Address>
    <Address>
      <Country>Pakistan</Country>
    </Address>
  </Customers>
</MyCustomer>
```

while i required the transform like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyCustomer>
  <Customers>
    <CutomerCode>C001</CutomerCode>
    <CustomerName>Shahbaz</CustomerName>
    <Address>
      <City>Karachi</City>
      <Country>Pakistan</Country>
    </Address>
    <CutomerCode>C002</CutomerCode>
    <CustomerName>Imran</CustomerName>
    <Address>
      <City>Lahore</City>
      <Couontry>Pakistan</Couontry>
    </Address>
  </Customers>
</MyCustomer>
```

Please Help I want the transformation correctly.please help i want the correct xslt method please help

Comment: How is it related to ASP.NET or WCF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to unwrap the individual `Customers`?

It looks like your stylesheet wasn't working because of these two templates:

```
<xsl:template match="Customers/City">
      <xsl:element name="Address">
         <xsl:element name="City">
       <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="Customers/Country">
      <xsl:element name="Address">
         <xsl:element name="Country">
       <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
```

These are giving you two different `Address` elements.

You *could* do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="Customers/City">
    <Address>
        <City>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </City>
        <Country>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Country"/>
        </Country>
    </Address>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Customers/Country"/>
```

Here's a similar XSLT 1.0 stylesheet that gives the wanted result and is a little cleaner in my opinion:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MyCustomer">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <Customers>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </Customers>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Customers">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::City) and not(self::Country)]"/>
        <Address>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="City|Country"/>
        </Address>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<MyCustomer>
   <Customers>
      <CutomerCode>C001</CutomerCode>
      <CustomerName>Shahbaz</CustomerName>
      <Address>
         <City>Karachi</City>
         <Country>Pakistan</Country>
      </Address>
      <CutomerCode>C002</CutomerCode>
      <CustomerName>Imran</CustomerName>
      <Address>
         <City>Lahore</City>
         <Country>Pakistan</Country>
      </Address>
   </Customers>
</MyCustomer>
```